# Pushing values from one array to another

Tags: php, arrays, function, pdo, associative-array

Anyone know how to get from this:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 ) 
Array ( [0] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 1 ) 
Array ( [0] => 0 )
```

to this:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 0 )
```

I'm having trouble getting towards the answer; any snippets or examples would be greatly appreciated. **Please don't comment about vulnerabilities in the code; I know it's already there. I am just a beginner...I just want the core guts of it to work.**

My code that I am using:

```
    // Function that checks if items are already discontinued or not
function checkDiscontinued($dbh, $idDiscontinuedArray) {

    try {
        foreach ($idDiscontinuedArray as $id) {
            $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT discontinued FROM `$id` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1");
            $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

            print_r($rows);
            echo '<br>';
            }

        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($idDiscontinuedArray as $id) {
            $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT discontinued FROM `$id` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1");
            $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

            $tempArr[] = $rows[0];
            }
 print_r($tempArr);
```